# Calling different fragments from a single fragment using button

Tags: android

I have a fragment with three button in it. Based on the button pressed i want to call another three fragment.my top fragment is as below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ramakanta_chandra.chechiacc.BlankFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    android:autoText="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="This is Video Segment"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="This is Audio Segment"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="This is Ebook Segment"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/videoimageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:src="@mipmap/video"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/audioimageButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:src="@mipmap/audio"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:src="@mipmap/book"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

now i want to call three different fragment named as BlankFragment4(),BlankFragment5(),BlankFragment6(). for this my code is

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
  View myview;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    final FragmentManager fm3 = getFragmentManager();
    ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.videoimageButton);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fm3.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment2, new BlankFragment4() )
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
    ImageButton bt2 = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.audioimageButton);
    bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fm3.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment2, new BlankFragment5() )
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            // Do something in response to button click
        }
    });
    ImageButton bt3 = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.audioimageButton);
    bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fm3.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment2, new BlankFragment6() )
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            // Do something in response to button click
        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return myview;
}
```

}

It is not working. For this operation i didn't write anything in the main activity.

Comment: What is actually happening when you say it is not working?

Comment: Change your LinearLayout with id 'fragment2' to FrameLayout and Try to  put your whole layout in ScrollView.

Comment: follow to @ρяσѕρєя K Answer......

Comment: App was getting hanged when i clicked any of the buttons. I made separate instance for each transaction now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

As see here:

[Fragment.getView():](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView())

> Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

and you are calling `getView` method inside `onCreateView` *before returning Fragment layout view from it*.

So use `myview` View object for accessing View's from Fragment layout.like:

```
ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton)myview.findViewById(R.id.videoimageButton);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ρяσѕρєя K